# How to add a StringBuilder object in snippet in MarkerOptions in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, stringbuilder

I am trying to add address from Geocoder class to be displayed in the snippet of marker. But the snippet does not accept StringBuilder object. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Following is my code

```
StringBuilder str;
            try
            {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(HistoryLocation.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitudeDouble, longitudeDouble, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if(geocoder.isPresent())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "geocoder present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Address returnaddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String locality = returnaddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnaddress.getCountryName();
                    String countrycode = returnaddress.getSubLocality();
                    String zip = returnaddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(locality + "");
                    str.append(city + "" +countrycode);
                    str.append(zip + "");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "geocoder not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            String dateAndTime = date + "-" + time;

            MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitudeDouble, longitudeDouble);
            mOptions.position(latlng);
            mOptions.title(dateAndTime);
            mOptions.snippet(str);;

            userMarker = googleMap.addMarker(mOptions);
            userMarker.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `toString()` on a `StringBuilder` to get a `String`, and pass the `String` to `snippet()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `MarkerOptions.snippet()` method takes a String parameter. Change:

```
mOptions.snippet(str);;
```

to:

```
mOptions.snippet(str.toString());
```